# How to figure out which object is exported by the export = syntax

Tags: typescript

I have a question about the content of  a `*.d.ts` file:

```
export = Keycloak;

//1
declare function Keycloak(config?: Keycloak.KeycloakConfig | string): Keycloak.KeycloakInstance;

//2
declare namespace Keycloak {
...
```

I am not sure whether the `export = Keycloak` above exports **both** the function and the namespace or only one of them and if so which.

I have read the following in the typescript documentation:

> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from
> the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or
> enum.

which would imply that only one of the above is exported by this syntax but I can't figure out which one since they have the same name...

Can someone help?

See complete content of file here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/keycloak.d.ts

Comment: If you import this file, what TypeScript will see is a class `Keycloak` that can be initialized *and* it will see a namespace `Keycloak` which has bunch of classes. If you were to generate a JS file, it would look like a class `Keycloak` with static members which would represent each of the classes inside the `Keycloak` namespace. **So basically it really exports both of them**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*.d.ts` file is only type declaration. It will not affect the real javascript code. So what is accessable depends on the js implementation `keycloak.js`

For typescript itself, it will export "both". Because the namespace is just to attach the export values to the namespace object.

Here give you a simple demo

```
function Keycloak(): void{}

namespace Keycloak {
  export const value = 1
}

export = Keycloak
```

The compiled js code is

```js
"use strict";
function Keycloak() { }
(function (Keycloak) {
    Keycloak.value = 1;
})(Keycloak || (Keycloak = {}));
module.exports = Keycloak;
```

You can see there is only one value `Keycloak`. The exported `value` is attached to it. That is why I use quotes on "both".

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAaQKYE8IBs4EMDWAFAJQBciAbnDACYDeAvgLABQrYuAtqgM4AOuCKhQZsefIjqtEiVAA8+cAE5REEBD1UVcWEMIC8iAIytmbFvMUrEhtJhwFWrIA)

Answer (score -1):

Try it?

1. Try using `KecCloak` in another file
2. Compile and check javascript output

Comment: Can you be more specific and/or add further explanations please?

Comment: @balteo Its as simple as importing it and then attempting to use it. You will see if it works as a function or not